# How to move a carousel item to the middle when it's clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

How can I make the carousel center the item I've clicked to the middle? I've looked everywhere for an answer but they're not straight answers... Can someone help me in this, please?

This is what I've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/sp9Jv/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="carousel">
        <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">next</a>

        <div class="viewport">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Un</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deux</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trois</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quatre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cinq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sept</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Huit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- viewport -->

    </div>
    <!-- carousel -->
</div>
<!-- wrapper -->
```

JavaScript:

```
var carousel = $('#carousel'),
    prev = carousel.find('.prev'),
    next = carousel.find('.next'),
    viewport = carousel.find('.viewport'),
    item = viewport.find('li'),
    itemWidth = item.outerWidth(true),
    itemNum = item.length,
    itemList = viewport.find('ul');

itemList.width(itemWidth * itemNum);

var moveCarousel = function(dir) {
    itemList.animate({ left: '-=' + (itemWidth  * dir) + 'px' }, 400);  
};

//prev
prev.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveCarousel(-1);
});

//next
next.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveCarousel(1);
});

//carousel item
item.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var self = $(this),
        selfIndex = self.index(),
        distance = itemList.width() / 2,
        selfPos = self.position(),
        selfPosLeft = selfPos.left,
        viewportPosLeft = viewport.position().left;

    e.preventDefault();

    //move item to middle, but it doesn't work... 
    if (selfPosLeft > Math.floor(viewport.width())/3) {
        itemList.animate({ left: '-' + Math.floor(viewport.width())/3 + 'px' }, 400);
    }

    if (selfPosLeft < Math.floor(viewport.width())/3) {
        itemList.animate({ left: Math.floor(viewport.width())/3 + 'px' }, 400);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#carousel {
    position: relative;
}
.viewport {
    width: 260px;
    border: 1px solid #6e6e6e;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.prev, .next {
    position: absolute;
}
.prev {
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
.next {
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
}

.viewport ul {
    position: absolute;
}
.viewport li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.viewport li a {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Does your carousel always only show three items or can it be more?

Comment: It can be any number, but for this example only 3. I just want something to give me a head start then I can adapt it later...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you have prepared all the information needed about all items, you can calculate the value of the left based on the clicked item.

Here is my modification:

and I've bound the click action of carousel items with this function and passed the clicked item using the self keyword.

```
var itemClicked=function(item){
    var itemIndex=$(item).index(),
        newLeft=(itemIndex*itemWidth*-1)+Math.floor(($(viewport).width()/itemWidth)/2)*itemWidth;
    $(itemList).animate({left:newLeft+"px"},400);
};
```

You can check it working on this url: http://jsfiddle.net/rUZHg/3/

I assume that this should work despite of the number of viewed elements while it calculates the padding between the left 0 and the left of the center element.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it's ugly, I hope it gives you some ideas.

I created a global `currentItem` that tracks what's in the center. Every time the carousel moves this is updated.

The very useful variable I found was `selfPosLeft` which told me what was being clicked. I should add that `90` was the multiple I got from clicking around. Must be linked to your CSS and I don't know how to find this number dynamically.

Please try it :) http://jsfiddle.net/sp9Jv/4/

Well, I'm picturing that when you have more than 3 items you can change the code to compute the difference between the current item and the `selfPosLeft` of the clicked one, I'll leave that to you :) Like this, seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/sp9Jv/5/