# jquery carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jcarousel

I am trying to get a jquery carousel working after I have moved the HTML into an empty div using .html()...

```
 $("#mydiv li a").click(function(e){
    if($(this).children('div').length > 0 ){
        var details = $(this).children("div").html(); 
        $("#info div").html(details); 
        openInfo();
    } else{
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent click
    }
});
```

Here is the function(openInfo) that animates a div onto the page. When this opens it has the carousel on it, but I can't get it working.

```
function openInfo(){
    $('#info').animate({
        height: windowHeight
    }, 900, function() {
        $("#info div").fadeIn(100);
    });
}
```

I am using jcarousel, I have it working on a different part of the page so it is working elsewhere. How can I get jcarousel to recognize the #info carousel after moving html into it? Any help/ advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code on pastebin ? It'll be easier to check your problem

Comment: where is your script for the jcarousel, put it inside that openInfo function

Comment: Here is link on pastebin to code, I added the jcarousel code into my openInfo function... http://pastebin.com/H4H4c0q6

Comment: I would like to know what your HTML looks like please. Could you add this to pastebin too?

Comment: Look here as the solutions provided in the two (first) answers work nice:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158497/how-to-move-a-carousel-item-to-the-middle-when-its-clicked-in-jquery