# Carousel to move item to middle and open modal

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I was looking at this question(link below)which moves clicked item to centre and I'd like to experiment with a functionality which will work like this:

[How to move a carousel item to the middle when it's clicked in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158497/how-to-move-a-carousel-item-to-the-middle-when-its-clicked-in-jquery)

1- User clicks on item and item moves to middle

2- Once transition is finished, it opens a modal or lightbox which will contain some information.

Questions you may be able to help me with(Please note I'm not experienced front end designer but trying):

Q1 - Is there any existing plugin to be able to do this? I've done some research and closest result I could find was this question mentioned above

Q2 - If there isn't, are you aware of anything similar? or how I can determine once the item is moved to middle to open a pop up?

Please find example here

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="carousel">
    <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>

    <div class="viewport">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Un</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Deux</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trois</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quatre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cinq</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sept</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Huit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- viewport -->

</div>
<!-- carousel -->
```

```
var carousel = $('#carousel'),
    prev = carousel.find('.prev'),
    next = carousel.find('.next'),
    viewport = carousel.find('.viewport'),
    item = viewport.find('li'),
    itemWidth = item.outerWidth(true),
    itemNum = item.length,
    itemList = viewport.find('ul');

itemList.width(itemWidth * itemNum);

var moveCarousel = function(dir) {
    itemList.animate({ left: '-=' + (itemWidth  * dir) + 'px' }, 400);  
};

//prev
prev.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveCarousel(-1);
});

//next
next.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveCarousel(1);
});

//carousel item
item.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var self = $(this),
        selfIndex = self.index(),
        distance = itemList.width() / 2,
        selfPos = self.position(),
        selfPosLeft = selfPos.left,
        viewportPosLeft = viewport.position().left;

    e.preventDefault();

    //move item to middle, but it doesn't work... 
    if (selfPosLeft > Math.floor(viewport.width())/3) {
        itemList.animate({ left: '-' + Math.floor(viewport.width())/3 + 'px' }, 400);
    }

    if (selfPosLeft < Math.floor(viewport.width())/3) {
        itemList.animate({ left: Math.floor(viewport.width())/3 + 'px' }, 400);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sp9Jv/

It is a bit clunky and it carries on looping on empty area (so it doesn't recognise the last item) but it is a good start

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of how many images you have in the item list, and move the carousel back to the start once this has been reached.  I have added an updated fiddle.  Hopefully you should be able to do something with this and improve on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/sp9Jv/33/

```
var carousel = $('#carousel'),
    prev = carousel.find('.prev'),
    next = carousel.find('.next'),
    viewport = carousel.find('.viewport'),
    item = viewport.find('li'),
    itemWidth = item.outerWidth(true),
    itemNum = item.length,
    itemList = viewport.find('ul'),
    itemLength = item.length,
    start = 0;

itemList.width(itemWidth * itemNum);

var moveCarousel = function(dir) {
    itemList.animate({ left: '-=' + (itemWidth  * dir) + 'px' }, 400);  
};

var moveToStart = function() {
    itemList.animate({ left: '0px' }, 400); 
    start = 0;
};

//prev
prev.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(start > 0){
        moveCarousel(-1);
        start --
    }
});

//next
next.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    start ++    
   if(start > itemLength-1){
        moveToStart();
   } else {
        moveCarousel(1);
   }
});

//carousel item
item.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var self = $(this),
        selfIndex = self.index(),
        distance = itemList.width() / 2,
        selfPos = self.position(),
        selfPosLeft = selfPos.left,
        viewportPosLeft = viewport.position().left;

    e.preventDefault();

    //move item to middle, but it doesn't work... 
    if (selfPosLeft > Math.floor(viewport.width())/3) {
        itemList.animate({ left: '-' + Math.floor(viewport.width())/3 + 'px' }, 400);
    }

    if (selfPosLeft < Math.floor(viewport.width())/3) {
        itemList.animate({ left: Math.floor(viewport.width())/3 + 'px' }, 400);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can see what you've done and it works great, only challenge left here is to open a modal or lighbox once item is moved to centre. Any ideas how to achieve that?